# Is there a way to change or transfer my Pokemon Go to a different Google account?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been playing the game a while now and have ranked up considerably. I'm wondering if there is any way to change to a different Google account and still keep all of my Pokemon/items etc, as I stupidly used my university gmail account when I first downloaded the app (which will be automatically deleted in September).

Is there any way to transfer my trainer/Pokemon/items etc to a different Google account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you change your email for Pokemon go](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275329/can-you-change-your-email-for-pokemon-go)

Comment: @camelCase I would leave this one open, and close the other question.  This one was asked first.

Comment: @TimmyJim - I think the other question has less noise, and has a better answer

Answer (score 3):

So far, [Niantic support](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us) only provides these categories for submitting requests:

- Request a nickname or team change
- Delete my Pokémon GO account
- Report an issue with a Gym or PokéStop
- Report inappropriate gameplay
- Report inappropriate Trainer behavior
- Report a bug
- Help with PokéCoins and premium items

There is no category that might fit in with issues around changing an email address, but you may make a request anyway in e.g. the "nickname or team change" category and share your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there doesn't appear to be a way.  [Ninantic doesn't support it](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/227084467):

> At this time, you cannot switch your account from one email address to another email address or merge two accounts.