# Can you change your email for Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it possible to change the email associated with Pokemon go? I used my collage email which will soon be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

That depends on your account type.

- With a trainer account you can simply change it on the [Pokémon Club](https://club.pokemon.com/sso/login) website.
- Using gmail I seriously doubt you can do that. While it is possible to change google's primary mail it's very unlikely to migrate college accounts to private ones and keep the profile ID. In that case I'd file a [support ticket](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us) to Niantic asking for a gmail change.

Comment: The Pokemon Club website link seems broken.

Comment: Note an anonymous user says: Deleting the college email doesn't delete the Google account...go too accounts.google.com and change the email used to login where it says "Login options" (or something similar)

Same Google account, different login info